# Get list of all input objects using JavaScript, without accessing a form object

Tags: javascript, html, input, field

I need to get all the `input` objects and manipulate the `onclick` param.

The following does the job for `<a>` links. Looking for something like this for `input` tags.

```js
for (var ls = document.links, numLinks = ls.length, i=0; i<numLinks; i++){
  var link = unescape(ls[i].href);
  link = link.replace(/\\'/ig,"#");
  if(ls[i].href.indexOf("javascript:") == -1)
  {
    ls[i].href = "javascript:LoadExtern(\\""+link+"\\",\\"ControlPanelContent\\",true,true);";
  }
}
```

Comment: Ouch, that's ugly and has several escaping problems. You don't ever want to use `javascript` URLs. My suggestion for this particular code: leave the `href` where it is and instead just set `ls[i].onclick= function() { LoadExtern(this.href, 'ControlPanelContent', true, true); };`.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

*(See update at end of answer.)*

You can get a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) of all of the `input` elements via `getElementsByTagName` ([DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094), [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439(VS.85).aspx)), then simply loop through it:

```
var inputs, index;

inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    // deal with inputs[index] element.
}
```

There I've used it on the `document`, which will search the entire document. It also exists on individual elements ([DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D)), allowing you to search only their descendants rather than the whole document, e.g.:

```
var container, inputs, index;

// Get the container element
container = document.getElementById('container');

// Find its child `input` elements
inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    // deal with inputs[index] element.
}
```

...but you've said you don't want to use the parent `form`, so the first example is more applicable to your question (the second is just there for completeness, in case someone else finding this answer needs to know).

---

**Update**: `getElementsByTagName` is an absolutely fine way to do the above, but what if you want to do something slightly more complicated, like just finding all of the checkboxes instead of all of the `input` elements?

That's where the useful `querySelectorAll` comes in: It lets us get a list of elements that match **any CSS selector we want**. So for our checkboxes example:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
```

You can also use it at the element level. For instance, if we have a `div` element in our `element` variable, we can find all of the `span`s with the class `foo` that are inside that `div` like this:

```
var fooSpans = element.querySelectorAll("span.foo");
```

`querySelectorAll` and its cousin `querySelector` (which just finds the *first* matching element instead of giving you a list) are supported by all modern browsers, and also IE8.

Comment: why did you use ++index? The elements in NodeList start with 0..so that way, you skip the first element??

Comment: @Alko: I *don't* skip the first. The first value of `index` within the loop **is** `0`. The `++index` doesn't happen until after the first loop iteration.

Comment: Will this get nested elements? For example if I have a form and then inside that form there's a table, and inside that table there is row, and inside that row there is an input - will this actually get that input? I think it might only work for top level inputs. I need to get ALL inputs, nested or not nested. Probably need recursion

Comment: @MobileMon - Yes, it works for non-child descendant elements. I'm not aware of any DOM **method** that finds elements that only looks at child elements, in fact. (Only DOM **collections**, like `children` and `childNodes`.).

Answer (score 16):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a **NodeList** which has its own [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( input => {
  // ...
});
```

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) now returns an **HTMLCollection** instead of a *NodeList*. So you would first need to convert it to an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to have access to methods like map and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach( input => {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  // ...
}
```