# Javascript - get element (button) without ID or Class?

Tags: javascript, html, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get list of all `input` objects using JavaScript, without accessing a `form` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214066/get-list-of-all-input-objects-using-javascript-without-accessing-a-form-obj)

How can I get elements, like all buttons on a page, without class or ID?

Is there anything like this?

```
document.getElementsByType(button)
```

EDIT

My confusion was how to get all buttons (not just one) without class or ID.

the solution ended up being

```
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; ++i) {
```

but your answer is what led me to find out what I didn't know to ask in the first place...
So, thanks everyone!

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('button') you mean?

Comment: @StiveKnx, seriously, if this isn't a duplicate you should have just answered with that comment (albeit with some explanation, maybe, and/or links to references).

Comment: @David Thomas, Sorry, but I wasn't sure if is really that what he wanted, maybe he wants to get all elements which type is "button", example: `<input type="button" />`

Comment: @StiveKnx he will get all elements which type is "button" with document.getElementsByTagName('button')...

Comment: @happytimeharry: How is `getElementsByTagName('button')` going to fetch an element that has the tagName `input`?

Comment: @am not i am - well, if you are like the OP and looking to get _button_ (TAGS) on a page, then that's what you should use.

Comment: @thescientist: Where does OP state all button TAGS? There are different types of buttons. *StiveKnx* gave one example. *happytime harry* suggested that `gEBTN` would fetch those as well. I asked how that's possible when the example given has a different *tagName*. I've still received no answer.

Comment: "How can I get elements, like all buttons on a page, without class or ID?". I took that to mean <button>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')
```

Comment: didn't say you did.  just a question posed in general.  It always bothers me when people get down voted but no one ever leaves a comment/explanation.

Comment: heh... probably Brandan upset he didnt get the answer!

Comment: It might, but it didn't. I always comment on my downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

There's [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName), [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector), and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll), among others. Take your pick!