# Filter getElementsByTagName list by option values

Tags: filtering, getelementsbytagname

I'm using getElementsByTagName to return all the select lists on a page - is it possible to then filter these based upon an option value, ie of the first or second item in the list?

The reason is that for reasons I won't go into here there are a block of select lists with number values (1,2,3,4,5 etc) and others which have text values (Blue and Black, Red and Black etc) and I only want the scripting I have to run on the ones with numerical values.  I can't add a class to them which would more easily let me do this however I can be certain that the first option value in the list will be "1".

Therefore is there a way to filter the returned list of selects on the page by only those whose first option value is "1"?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that there is a better solution, but for the moment you can try something like:

```
var allSelect = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

var result = filterBy(allSelect, 0/*0 == The first option*/, "1"/* 1 == the value of the first option*/);


function filterBy(allSelect, index, theValue) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < allSelect.length; i++) {
        if(allSelect[i].options[index].value == theValue ) {
            result.push(allSelect[i]);
        }    
    }
    return result;            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried giving it a go adapting to existing script but my skills obviously aren't good enough.  The pre-existing fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/hBf2t/17/ if that is of any help and I've added in a new (commented out) select list (which should be skipped by the filter mentioned above) as well as a comment in the j/s where I think the filtering should be taking place.  All I need is the correct scripting to apply the filtering to my lists before doing anything else with them.

Comment: UPDATE: Managed to get it working by wrapping the action which is performed on each of the lists (so within the for loop like you have above) in this if statement "if (inputs[i].options[1].text == 1) {" (I had to change the options index from 0 to 1 as the 0 option was "Please select".

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working by wrapping a simple IF statement around the action to be performed (in this case, disabling options) as follows:

```
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].options[1].text == 1) {
      // perform action required
      }
    }
```

No doubt there is a slicker or more economic way to do this but the main thing is it works for me.