# How to list all the input fields,buttons in a web site?

Tags: html, gwt

I want to create a report where all the user input fields,buttons of a url and it's hyperlinks will be listed. Is there any tool available in the market?If available can it be run on GWT application?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214066/get-list-of-all-input-objects-using-javascript-without-accessing-a-form-obj) Stackoverflow-question

Comment: In the above link the input fields get counted by the js code of same application. In my case an external application will scan the targeted web application.