# Converting multiple text inputs simultaneously to upper case

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do the following things:

1. Create 3 text boxes and 1 button
2. Type lower case letters into the 3 boxes
3. Click on the button
4. Upon clicking on the button, the letters are converted to upper case

How come the letters I'm typing into the boxes aren't being converted to upper case?

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function upperCase() {
    var x = document.getElementById("form_1");
    x = x.value.toUpperCase();
} 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form_1" method="post">

Enter your name:
<input type="text" name="nameInput">

Enter your street address:
<input type="text" name="streetInput">

Enter your city/state:
<input type="text" name="cityStateInput">

<input type="button" name="upperCaseButton" value="Convert to Uppercase" 
 onclick="upperCase()">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to:

1) change the name for id, so you can retrieve each element by the ids.

```
<form name="form1" id="form_1" method="post">

Enter your name:
<input type="text" id="nameInput">

Enter your street address:
<input type="text" id="streetInput">

Enter your city/state:
<input type="text" id="cityStateInput">

<input type="button" id="upperCaseButton" value="Convert to Uppercase" 
 onclick="upperCase('nameInput'); upperCase('streetInput'); upperCase('cityStateInput');">

</form>
```

2) call thefunction for every input you want to convert its value to upper case.

```
upperCase = function(name) {
    var inp = document.getElementById(name);
    inp.value = inp.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

See ths demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gal007/tagLtyko/

Comment: that's what i'm talkin' about

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign the values of each individual `<input>` element to its uppercase version.  In the following script, I added a helper method which accepts an element id and attempts to change the value of that element to uppercase.  The `upperCase()` function is still the entry point, so you don't need to modify your HTML code at all.

```
<script>
    function upperCaseInput(var id) {
        var x = document.getElementById(id);
        x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
    }

    function upperCase() {
        upperCaseInput("nameInput");
        upperCaseInput("streetInput");
        upperCaseInput("cityStateInput");
    }
</script>
```

**Usage:**

```
<input type="button" name="upperCaseButton" value="Convert to Uppercase"
       onclick="upperCase()">
```

Comment: is there a way to modify the upperCase() function so that I can reference the form once instead of each individual input?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with pure JavaScript, but it might be possible using something like JQuery.

Comment: If you just want the appearance of the form elements to be in uppercase you can change the css text-transform propprty with js. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_texttransform.asp

Comment: Some good examples of how to handle the upperCase() function by getting all inputs and looping. [Can be seen in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214066/get-list-of-all-input-objects-using-javascript-without-accessing-a-form-obj). Although, CSS method mentioned by @Nillervision removes the need for a button press.

Comment: I don't like the CSS solution partly because if the CSS for the inputs is being used elsewhere on the page, the case may be changed in unwanted places.