# How to validate multiple text boxes to make sure they have letters only?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to validate many different text boxes with javascript and I don't want to have to getElementById for each one. How would you validate to make sure each text box has a word in it prior to a button submit?

```
    <table id="inputTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <P>Verb: <input type="text" required id="varA"></p>
      <P>Adjective: <input type="text" required id="varB"></p>
      <P>Noun (plural): <input type="text" required id="varC"></p>
      <P>Adjective: <input type="text" required id="varD"></p>
      <P>Verb enging in "ing": <input type="text" required id="varE"></p>
      <P>Verb: <input type="text" required id="varF"></p>
      <P>Number: <input type="text" required id="varG"></p>
      <P>Adjective: <input type="text" required id="varH"></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <P>Noun (plural): <input type="text" required id="varI"></p>
      <P>Noun (plural): <input type="text" required id="varJ"></p>
      <P>Noun (plural): <input type="text" required id="varK"></p>
      <P>Relative (plural): <input type="text" required id="varL"></p>
      <P>Adjective: <input type="text" required id="varM"></p>
      <P>Adjective: <input type="text" required id="varN"></p>
      <P>Noun (plural): <input type="text" required id="varO"></p>
      <P>Verb: <input type="text" required id="varP"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of all \`input\` objects using JavaScript, without accessing a \`form\` object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214066/get-list-of-all-input-objects-using-javascript-without-accessing-a-form-obj)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("input")` gets you a list of all input elements on the page. Or you can give them a common class and select by that. Then just loop over them and test the values. As an aside, shouldn't they have a `name` attribute if they're going to be submitted?

Comment: You have used `required` html5 attribute , then you dont need to worry about each text box has a word !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function submit_form() {
  all_input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
  console.log(all_input);
  for (var i = 0; i < all_input.length; ++i) {
    if (all_input[i].value.trim().match(/\w/) == null) {
      alert("You need to enter a word in each text box");
      return
    } 
  }
}
document.getElementById('fm').addEventListener('click',submit_form)
```

```html
<form >
  <table id="inputTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <P>Verb:
        <input type="text" required id="varA">
      </p>
      <P>Adjective:
        <input type="text" required id="varB">
      </p>
      <P>Noun (plural):
        <input type="text" required id="varC">
      </p>
      <P>Adjective:
        <input type="text" required id="varD">
      </p>
      <P>Verb enging in "ing":
        <input type="text" required id="varE">
      </p>
      <P>Verb:
        <input type="text" required id="varF">
      </p>
      <P>Number:
        <input type="text" required id="varG">
      </p>
      <P>Adjective:
        <input type="text" required id="varH">
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <P>Noun (plural):
        <input type="text" required id="varI">
      </p>
      <P>Noun (plural):
        <input type="text" required id="varJ">
      </p>
      <P>Noun (plural):
        <input type="text" required id="varK">
      </p>
      <P>Relative (plural):
        <input type="text" required id="varL">
      </p>
      <P>Adjective:
        <input type="text" required id="varM">
      </p>
      <P>Adjective:
        <input type="text" required id="varN">
      </p>
      <P>Noun (plural):
        <input type="text" required id="varO">
      </p>
      <P>Verb:
        <input type="text" required id="varP">
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <button type='submit' id="fm">SUbmit</button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `$('input[type=text]')` instead of getElementById for each text box..

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to each input: `pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"` -- it will prevent the form from being submitted if anything other than alpha characters are in the field -- assuming this is in an html `form`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 form validation allows a regex in the `pattern` attribute.  See MDN's Data form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `document.querySelectorAll` which returns a list of the elements within the document.

[More Reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Try this script with your existing code:

```
var txtbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
for(var i = 0;i<txtbox.length;i++)
{
  alert("Enter Text");
}
```